# How to convert array into string in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert an array in string in PHP so that I can store it into mySQL fields and reversely I can fetch:
Following is the data format:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "year" => "234"
    "amount" => "2387"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "year" => "23"
    "amount" => "324"
  ]
]
```

I'm trying something like this:

```
$var = implode(',', $data['revenues']);
```

I tried using implode but it is not working. Please help me out.

**Edit**

I tried this before:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, Research::$create_validation_rules);
    $data = $request->only(['coverage_date', 'company_id', 'contact_id', 'type', 'reco', 'target', 'projections', 'revenues', 'ebitas', 'profits']);
    $data['coverage_date'] = Carbon::parse($request->coverage_date)->toDateTimeString();
    $data['revenues'] = json_encode($data['revenues']);
    $data['projections'] = json_encode($data['projections']);
    $data['profits'] = json_encode($data['profits']);
    $research = Research::create($data);
    if($research)
    {
        return response()->json(['msg' => 'Successfully Created'], 200);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json(['msg' => 'Something went wrong'], 450);
    }
}
```

Error which I'm getting is:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: What exactly do you want it to look like when you store it on your database

Comment: `serialize()` or `json_encode()` are 2 possible choices. But if you want to be able to select this data again based on one of these fields storing a string is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

example

```
$array = [["year" => "234","amount" => "2387"],["year" => "23","amount" => "324"]];
/* 
   Depending on PHP Version you can pass additional parameters
   in json_encode for example json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) 
*/
$string = json_encode($array);
echo $string;
```

check this on [PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f607cdc07647c81644948bf16b2ab091f0b46d25)

Comment: I tried this first don't know why it is giving error

Comment: @NitishKumar What error are you getting ? Can you post the error message?

Comment: Updated the question please review.

Comment: @NitishKumar you posted the error line but i don't know exactly which one is which in your code the way i see it you have an error here `$research = Research::create($data);` `$data` is an array and your error is array to string conversion i think in that method you insert data to database. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes, I'm using laravel framework which accepts data in array format while using  the create method to insert into database

Comment: @NitishKumar either your error is there or it is here `Carbon::parse($request->coverage_date)->toDateTimeString();` as i see `Carbon::parse` will expect a string as input check if `$request->coverage_date` returns an array and gives an error.

Comment: No. I don't think so, when I do dd() it clears the code without throwing any error.

Comment: @NitishKumar right before `$data['coverage_date'] = ...` type `echo $request->coverage_date;` if you get an error there then that is your problem. Since you know the exact line the error is thrown why don't you share it by pointing the line number in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147314/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-and-peter-darmis).